# cannot reference React in Fable

Tags: reactjs, f#, fable-f#

I am trying to write a React component in F# with Fable, and I'm having trouble referencing the necessary libraries. The compile errors I'm getting are:

- The namespace 'React' is not defined. ('open' statements)
- The type PureStatelessComponent is not defined.

Here is my code

```
module ContactInfoComponent

open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.Import
open Fable.Import.Browser
open Fable.React
open Fable.React.Helpers


type ContactInfoProps = {
    Name : string
}

type ContactInfoComponent(initialProps) = 
    inherit PureStatelessComponent<ContactInfoProps>(initialProps)
    override this.render() = 

        div [] [ 
            str "Name: "
            input [Type "text" Id "txtName"]
        ]
```

Here are my dependencies in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "fable-compiler": "^2.4.18",
    "fable-loader": "^2.1.8",
    "fable-core": "^0.7.30",
    "fable-powerpack": "0.0.20",
    "fable-react": "^0.8.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
```

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll" />
    <Reference Include="node_modules/fable-powerpack/Fable.PowerPack.dll" />
    <Reference Include="node_modules/fable-react/Fable.React.dll" />
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.Browser.Dom" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

What can I do to solve these compile errors?

Comment: I think the npm versions of the Fable .NET packages (e.g. `fable-react`) are very out of date.  I'd suggest using the NuGet versions instead, as you have done for `Fable.Browser.Dom`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd suggest using the NuGet versions instead, as you have done for Fable.Browser.Dom. – Mark Pattison

Correct! I fixed the problem by adding the NuGet Package References in my .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.Core" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.Browser.Dom" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.React" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Fable.PowerPack" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now I'm going to see if I can remove these references from the package.config. I don't think my F# code is actually referencing the DLLs from the node_modules folder.